# Destroy ChartJS rendered with Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, chart.js

i have a little problem with my Symfony/ChartJS Application.

So if i create a Chart with JS like `var myChart = new Chart`.. and so on, i can easily destroy the Chart with `myChart.destory();` because i can address the ChartObject.

My Problem:
The first Chart i Render with my SymfonyController. So i render the chart in my Controller with

```
return $this->render('category.html.twig', [
         'chart' => $chart]);
```

In Twig i assign an ID to the Chart `{{ render_chart(chart, {'id': 'my-chart'}) }}`.
But i dont really know how i can adress the whole Chartobject in Js. So how i can destroy the Chart i created with my Symfonycontroller? Anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

//EDIT
The normal way with `const chart = Chart.getChart('my-chart');` don't work either. Here is my Canvas-ConsoleLog for more information:

```
<canvas data-controller="symfony--ux-chartjs--chart" data-symfony--ux-chartjs--chart-view-value="(i deleted the values for better legibility)" id="my-chart" style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 407.778px; width: 816.667px;" width="735" height="367"></canvas>
```

The strange thing:
when i try the log:  `console.log(document.getElementById("my-chart").getContext("2d"););` it shows:

```
  CanvasRenderingContext2D {canvas: canvas#my-chart, globalAlpha: 1, globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over', filter: 'none', imageSmoothingEnabled: true, …}
canvas: canvas#my-chart
direction: "ltr"
fillStyle: "#000000"
filter: "none"
font: "12px \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
globalAlpha: 1
globalCompositeOperation: "source-over"
imageSmoothingEnabled: true
imageSmoothingQuality: "low"
lineCap: "butt"
lineDashOffset: 0
lineJoin: "miter"
lineWidth: 1
miterLimit: 10
shadowBlur: 0
shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
shadowOffsetX: 0
shadowOffsetY: 0
strokeStyle: "#000000"
textAlign: "start"
textBaseline: "alphabetic"
[[Prototype]]: CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

so the log shows that the chart is recognized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

symfny-ux controller creates its [own instance of ChartJS](https://github.com/symfony/ux/blob/2.x/src/Chartjs/Resources/assets/src/controller.ts#L38) inside an appropriate stimulus-controller, and this variable isn't directly accessible. But, symfony/ux developers are smart, and they created **events** (e.g. `chartjs:connect`) which you can listen to ([link](https://github.com/symfony/ux/blob/2.x/src/Chartjs/Resources/assets/src/controller.ts#L40))

If you do so, you will end up with a JS native `CustomEvent` object and in the `details` property of this event you will find passed `chart` instance previously created in symfiny-ux-controller for chart.js
So in theory you would be able just to

```js
document.addEventListener("chartjs:connect",(chartEv) => { 
console.log(chartEv.details); // chartEv.details.chart.destroy()
});
```

I do recommend you to watch [Ryan's tutorial on Symfony UX](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stimulus), especially "Extending a UX Controller" chapter where he tries to work with previously created instance of `new Chart()` like in your case.

Comment: Tank you very much! I will try it soon, but i think this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getChart`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/developers/api.html#static-getchart-key) api method chart.js exposes on itself.

So when you know the ID of your canvas you can use this js to get the chart object:

```js
const chart = Chart.getChart('my-chart');
```

Comment: I already tried this.. Then i get the console log " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')"
So the Chart is there, i see in the specs that the canvas id is "my-Chart" but still i cant adress it with "const chart = Chart.getChart('my-chart');"..

Comment: if your id of the canvas is with a capital C then that is your problem. You will also need to capatalize the C in the getChart method.

Comment: My fault, the c is not Capital. I added some Information in the question